# Given PropertyInfo.PropertyType how to cast PropertyInfo.GetValue() to that type

Tags: c#, casting, propertyinfo

PropertyInfo.GetValue() returns an object. 
I need to cast that object to the type returned from PropertyInfo.PropertyType.
How can I do it?
The only way I think is a switch on PropertyType.ToString(). Is there another way?
TIA

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Do you mean at compile time, like `var x = (MyType)propertyInfo.GetValue(source)`?

Comment: @vc 74: exactly. Something like var x = (PropertyType)propertyInfo.GetValue(source).

Comment: @marcelo Then I don't see the issue, just use a similar code

Comment: How do you plan to declare a variable of the appropriate type to hold the result of this cast? That's the main issue with trying to work with runtime type information and mixing it with compile time concepts (such as inserting a cast which is our way of telling the compiler that we have more information about the type than it does, at compile time)

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, Generics can help with the problem Damien describes. `Public T GetValueOf<T>(PropertyInfo prop, Object source) => (T) prop.GetValue(source);`.  I can't test this at the moment, but it *should* work.

Answer (score 2):

It IS possible. With the PropertyInfo Value and PropertyType you can: var typedPropertyVal = Convert.ChangeType(propertyVal, propertyType); This is the post that helped me: technico.qnownow.com/reflection-setvalue-type-conversion

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not possible. You would need to choose what to do based on the type:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void FooFunc()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}

...

public void Whatever()
{
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.Foo = new Foo();
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeof(Bar).GetProperties())
    {
        // the compiler will not know what the property is!
        // it would only be known at runtime so you will not be 
        // able to access foo
        propertyInfo.PropertyType p = propertyInfo.GetValue(bar) as propertyInfo.PropertyType; // compiler error
        p.FooFunc(); // compiler error

        // you can do this:
        Foo p = propertyInfo.GetValue(bar) as Foo;
        if (p != null) // cast was successful
            p.FooFunc();
        // but you would need such a check for each type you want
        // to include

        // alternatively use conditions based on the type
        object p = propertyInfo.GetValue(bar);
        if (p.GetType() == typeof(Foo))
            ((Foo)p).FooFunc();

        // or with pattern matching
        switch propertyInfo.GetValue(bar)
        {
            case Foo f:
                f.FooFunc;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do want to add that there is a much cleaner conditional casting in newer versions of C# with: if(p is Foo foo)foo.fooFunc();

Comment: @bramve Actually switch/case pattern matching would be an even better solution in this case since there are probably multiple types to handle

Comment: @vc74 Ah yea for sure, gotta love the new notations for this kind of stuff :)

Comment: shiny new toys!

Comment: It **IS** possible. With the PropertyInfo Value and PropertyType you can:

`var typedPropertyVal = Convert.ChangeType(propertyVal, propertyType);`

This is the post that helped me: http://technico.qnownow.com/reflection-setvalue-type-conversion/

Comment: @RyanVanDerWal please post this as an answer instead of a comment so people coming here can easily find the answer rather than reading all the comments, something not everyone does.

Answer (score -4):

var prop= PropertyInfo.getValue() as Propertytype;
i use this for casting .

Comment: as a bad example

Comment: var filtre = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as string; is this code is bad and if it can you explain to me why !!!!  thx :)

Comment: no there's nothing wrong with that. We're talking about using the PropertyInfo.PropertyType which is a System.Type to cast an object. Casting to a known type is not an issue.